# How to apply domain to Many2One field in Odoo using a list of records

Tags: python, odoo

I have a entity "pay_activity" with an antivity (activity_id) and a purchase (purchase_id). 
The purchase has a list of activities related to that purchase (activity_ids). 
I want to apply a domain to activity, so the user can only select an activity in the list of Activities of the purchase (purchase_activity).
I have tried to apply the domain domain=[('id','in',purchase_activity)]  to the the activity field but it shows an error "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object".
How can I apply domain to the activity_id field to ensure that the user will only select an activity that is in the list of all activiities related to the purchase (purchase_activity)?
This is my code:

```
class CenterPayActivity(models.Model):

    _name = 'center.pay_activity'
    _description = 'Permite distribuir los pagos entre las actividades'


    purchase_id = fields.Many2one('center.purchase', string='pago')

    purchase_activity = fields.Many2many('center.activity', related="purchase_id.activity_ids")

    activity_id = fields.Many2one('center.activity', string='Actividad', required=True, domain=[('id','in',purchase_activity)] )
```

Answer (score 0):

String domains are supposed to be dynamic and evaluated on the client-side only.

Use the field domain in the the form view and it will apply when displaying existing records for selection:

```
<field name="activity_id" domain="[('id', 'in', purchase_activity)]"/>
```

Comment: sorry, but both methods are not working I have tried this code and it works, but I dont think It is a good idea to apply a domain from an onchange method. It is possible to apply that dynamic domain from other function, maybe when the forms opens?
`  @api.onchange('activity_id')
    def _change_activity(self):
        res={}
        res['domain']={'activity_id':[('id', 'in', self.get_ids())]}
        return res

    def get_ids(self):
        list_ids=[]
        for activity in self.purchase_activity:
            list_ids.append(activity.id)
        return list_ids`

Comment: I updated my answer and removed the domain used in the field definition (ORM). You need to use the domain in the form view. Check my edit.

Comment: Sorry, not working. The drop-down list is not showing any element and it supose to. I had to make "purchase_activity" present in the view, but not even that way works
`              <field name="activity_id" domain="[('id', 'in', purchase_activity)]"/>
              <field name="purchase_activity"  invisible= "1"/>`

Comment: It should work, I suspect the error comes from somewhere else. Please add a minimum example necessary to reproduce the issue?